# SAML 2.0 + Keycloak + Django

Tags: django, keycloak, saml, saml-2.0, django-saml2-auth

Hello I'm trying to implement Keycloak SAML 2.0 authentication with Django application.

I'm using [django_saml2_auth](https://github.com/fangli/django-saml2-auth) and I configured my project as I was instructed in the django_saml2_auth repo. My configuration of django_saml2_auth is:

```
SAML2_AUTH = {
    'METADATA_AUTO_CONF_URL': 'http://localhost/keycloak/auth/realms/master/protocol/saml/descriptor'
}
```

when I start the development server on localhost:8000 and go to /accounts/login I'm redirected to Keycloak and I have the following error:

```
We are sorry...
Unknown login requester
```

Do you know how to fix that? Do you know some well documented examples of Keycloak SAML 2.0 configuration with Django?

Answer (score 0):

I was using for implementing SAML2 Auth for django via Keycloak the followings projects: [python3-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml) and [django-saml-service-provider](https://github.com/KristianOellegaard/django-saml-service-provider), which you can take as a basis. You also need to properly configure the client in keylock in order to django can communicate with keycloak IDP.